# Intentando parar búsquedas con Find

Tags: bash, shell

La cuestión es que busco que, una vez encontrado un elemento que cumple las características, necesito hacer que `find` deje de buscar más.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $@
do
    find /home -name $file -uid +500 -exec echo "Fichero {} encontrado" \; -exec exit 1\;
done
```

El problema es que me devuelve el siguiente mensaje:

```
find: «exit»: No existe el fichero o el directorio
```

Comment: Vale, ese era el problema. Antes había probado con `-exec quit`, pero no con `-quit`. Un fallo tonto. Muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que quitar `-exec exit` y sustituirlo por `-quit` tal que:

```
  find /home -name $file -uid +500 -exec echo "Fichero {} encontrado" \; -quit
```

Comment: Cuando utilizo la expresión que me has recomendado me da el siguiente error: `find: paths must precede expression: ;
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]`. Pero, al utilizarlo sin el último `\;` no me da ningún tipo de error. ¿Tiene alguna razón?

Comment: si, que me he equivocado, ahora lo quito ^^'